# dissection of a $1\times 5$ rectangle to a square

Tags: geometry

I've been thinking about the following problem:

We have a $1\times 5$ rectangle: how to cut it and reassemble it such that it forms a square?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you allowed to overlap the pieces? Do you require that the resulting square have the same area as the rectangle?

Comment: yes... total area of the square should be 5

Comment: The inverse of this question can be found at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15181/divide-a-square-into-5-equal-squares/15183#15183.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it with four pieces, and translations only (no rotations).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very optimal. +1!

Answer (score 26):

[image]

Comment: While this is pretty impressive, how would you figure this out if you didn't already know the answer?  Is there a general technique being employed here, or is this problem-specific?

Comment: The area of your original rectangle is 5. A square with the same area must have sides of length $\sqrt{5}$. So thinking of the pythagorean theorem, we need $a^2+b^2=5$. The only positive integer solution is $a,b=1,2$. This led me to chop off a rectangle of size $1\times 2$ and slice it diagonally. It then made sense to do it again and then sliding things around we get the above answer. That's how I thought about it anyway. The hard part was drawing it in Microsoft Paint :)

Answer (score 10):

A standard approach to finding solutions to problems like this is to overlay two tilings. In the following image, the bright yellow rectangles give one 5-piece and two 4-piece solutions requiring only translations (one of which is the same as Robert Israel’s above):

$\hspace{1.15in}$ [image: tilings]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that is surely far from optimal.

First, cut it into 5 $1\times1$ squares, and arrange them into a $2\times2$ square sitting next to a $1\times1$. Now there's a standard way to cut two squares into a total of four pieces that rearrange to form a single square. I wish I knew how to draw pictures. Anyway, let the small square be $ABCD$ With $C$ a vertex of the big square and $CD$ along the side $CEFG$ of the big square. Find $H$ on $CG$ such that $GH=AB$. Cut along $FH$ and along $AH$. Then the bits $FHG$, $ABH$, and $ADEFHA$ can be moved to form a square.

[image: 5 square dissection]

Comment: Googling for Pythagoras' theorem gives a couple of usefull pictures, e.g this one: http://goo.gl/PuAz7

Comment: ... or this one: http://goo.gl/DcLWS

Comment: If you want to draw pictures on MSE, draw them on anything you want as long as you can get them in a file format that allows you to upload them here. There's a button to upload images directly in your answers when you're answering... find it =) personally I am a fan of picturing my blackboard with my Android phone!

Comment: @Patrick, thanks, but I'm on the road, using whatever computers I can find, and the only thing I can draw on is a napkin. But I'll keep your advice in mind.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson : You have no idea what can come out of a napkin... =P

Answer (score 0):

Cut a small square out of it and throw the rest away.  If you are not allowed to throw any part away, then crumple the rest into a ball and stack it on the square.  If you are not allowed to throw any part away and you are not allowed to overlap pieces, then I don't know the answer.

Edit:

> Now there's a standard way to cut two squares into a totasl of four
>   peices that rearrange to form a single square.
>   I wish I knew how to draw pictures.

[image: squares]
<sub>(source: [cut-the-knot.org](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/proof13.gif))</sub>

Comment: When you copy something from another post, common practice is to acknowledge the source. But thanks for supplying the picture.

Answer (score 0):

We can consider this problem in terms of a tiling of the plane with squares. Or equivalently, we treat the large square as a torus, i.e., its top edge is glued to its bottom edge, and its left edge is glued to its right edge. Thus all the current solutions on this page are essentially equivalent.

[image: Tessellation illustrating the dissection of a square into 5 congruent squares]

Note that all of those right triangles are similar to the triangle with sides $1, 2, \sqrt5$.